# Laravel storage disk put gives internal server error 500 on live server | no logs are created

Tags: php, laravel, image, download, storage

I am saving image files to disk. After that I create a ZIP and download it. Everything works fine on localhost.

On the live server I get:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

The error occurs if I want to save an image to the storage:

```
$user = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users')->where('id', $userid)->first();
Storage::disk('gdpr')->put($user->picture, file_get_contents(env('AVATAR_PHOTO_SRC') . $user->picture));
```

`env('AVATAR_PHOTO_SRC')` is the absoulte path to the image, example: `https://example.com/uploads/thumb/`

---

There is no log file created. And the size of the zip is less then 1MB, images are even smaller.

What is happening here?

**EDIT**

`$user->picture` is the name of the file. example: `example.jpg`.

The file does exist and can be opened for example in the browser. Remember everything works fine on localhost.

**EDIT**

I found a log in try, catch:

```
file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
```

**EDIT**

PHP ini cant be modified on a shared server. I will need an alternative way to store the image.

Comment: What is `$user->picture`? Is it path? Does an image actually exist on `env('AVATAR_PHOTO_SRC') . $user->picture)`? You may also want to try/catch the put statement.

Comment: @QumberRizvi  See my edit please

Comment: @QumberRizvi I found something with try catch, see my update. It seems I cant store images this way, because I cant change server config.

Comment: Please edit your php.ini to allow url_fopen: `allow_url_fopen = 1
allow_url_include = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the curl solution, which worked for me:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, env('AVATAR_PHOTO_SRC') . $user->picture);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CAINFO, Storage::disk('other')->path("cacert-2020-01-01.pem")); 
$img = curl_exec($c);

$httpCode_post = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$cerror_post = curl_error($c);

curl_close($c); 

Storage::disk('gdpr')->put($user->picture, $img);
```

You can set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false then you dont need the step with the certificate.

But I advise you to add the certificate. Its super easy. Just download it [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and save it somewhere in your storage.

Answer (score 1):

**From PHP : [www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)**

> allow_url_fopen boolean
>
> This option enables the URL-aware fopen wrappers that enable accessing
>   URL object like files. Default wrappers are provided for the access of
>   remote files using the ftp or http protocol, some extensions like zlib
>   may register additional wrappers.

So you may need to enable `allow_url_fopen=1` in your php.ini to enable ftp or http protocol.

Comment: I know this. Will close the question. I need an alternative way for file_get_contents. PHP ini cant be modified on a shared server. I will need an alternative way to store the image.

Comment: You might want to talk to your hosting provider. They do sometimes allow these operation if you ask nicely. :)

Comment: @Roman there is a good library to work with images see: https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/introduction/